# Angular 2, interact with a bootstrap component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, dom

How can I use inside an Angular 2  page a getboostrap component that need some javascript initializations and dom accesses for interacts?

For Example:
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: I would recommend to use the bootstrap directives for angular2. E.g. https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/

Comment: Yes I've already seen ng2-boostrap project but unfortunately the "slider" input control is missing. Thanks.